# eclipse plungin for testing and coding standard

Tags: eclipse

I wanted to know if there is a code style checking pulgin in eclipse for C/C++ code. we have a code style document which we want to emphasize. Also is there a plugin in eclipse for testing C/C++ code. A plugin which will do unit testing and static code analysis.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For Java, most style-guide issues can be handled by [Checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/). For rules that are more to do with avoiding bugs than simple consistency, there is also [findbugs](http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/).

A common practise is to set a central build using jenkins, maven and sonar that runs both of those, and perhaps some other tools, in a standard configuration. The results of that centralised analysis can be loaded back into eclipse with the [sonar plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/developer-tools/eclipse/)

This should work with any [C/C++ code analysis tool](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/installation-and-usage/) supported by sonar.

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of plugin [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/). You can choose any plugin which suites to your need.